# Azure AD B2C outgoing IP addresses

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I've a custom policy that reaches out to other services via a RESTful technical profiles for claims processing.  I need to whitelist the IP address range of the AD B2C instance to allow connection to these services as they reside outside of the Azure domain.

I've come across this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37845671/azure-ad-b2c-policy-ip-addresses-to-allow-access-to-custom-policy-html-template), and the updated set of data center IP addresses for Azure [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56519).

A few questions

- Are there different IP addresses for Azure AD B2C than Azure AD or are they both covered by the "AzureIdentity" system services in the 2nd link?
- If the latter, which set of IP addresses are relevant to Azure AD B2C, "AzureActiveDirectoryDomainServices" or "AzureActiveDirectory.ServiceEndpoint" ?
- Finally, is there a more definitive way to scope down the set of IP addresses, e.g. by region or perhaps by addressPrefix as with Azure Functions via the resource explorer and a resource profile?

TIA

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not possible. The outgoing IPs will be in the Azure Datacentre IP range. Anyone can stand up a VM in this ip range. Rather than use network security, work on API authentication schemes described here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/secure-rest-api

Comment: Thanks Jas, first for the straight forward answer and second for the copious custom profile examples that you've provided to the community.  Needed some insight into the address range to get things hooked up to a temporary dev environment.  Planning on locking down via certs as recommended in the reference.  Cheers.

Comment: @JasSuri-MSFT
With the remark 'Not possible' are you implying that it is not possible to whitelist IP addresses for B2C outgoing requests? 

I would like to use whitelisted IPs on top of the API authentication schemes. 

I am a little confused on which IPs I should whitelist from the 'Azure IP Ranges and Service Tags – Public Cloud' list. The official docs say this: 'The request to your REST API service comes from Azure AD B2C servers. The REST API service must be published to a publicly accessible HTTPS endpoint. The REST API calls will arrive from an Azure data center IP address.'

Comment: It’s not possible because you have to allowlist the entire published ip range set…